# Data frame indexing not working as it should be. Does not give error as well. Pandas-Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say we have a dataframe:
'''

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8)**2})
df
```

'''

I am trying to set Values of column C to np.nan for a range of values in column C.

I am trying to set nan values for all values in C that are less than 2 and greater than 5.

I am doing like this:

```
'''df.loc[(df['C']<2) & (df['C']>5),'C']=np.nan'''
```

It does not give any error or warning but also does nothing and the dataframe remains the same.

Does anyone know whats going on? I also tried (not recommended solutions) but they also did not work:

```
''' 
df['C'][(df['C']<2) & (df['C']>5)]=np.nan

df['C'].loc[(df['C']<2) & (df['C']>5)]=np.nan
'''
```

Comment: looks like you need or and not `&` `df.loc[(df['C']<2) | (df['C']>5),'C']=np.nan` ?

Comment: Oh God, of course i need an OR. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `C` contains a single value , you would need an OR instead of an and, please use:

```
df.loc[(df['C']<2) | (df['C']>5),'C']=np.nan
```